# How can I update a serialized HashMap contained in a file?

Tags: java, serialization

I have a file that contains a serialized HashMap containing an element of type MyObject:

```
�� sr java.util.HashMap���`� F 
loadFactorI     thresholdxp?@     w      t (a54d88e06612d820bc3be72877c74f257b561b19sr  com.myproject.MyObject C�m�I�/ I  partitionL hashcodet Ljava/lang/String;L idt Ljava/lang/Long;L offsetq ~ L    timestampq ~ L topicq ~ xp    q ~ ppppx
```

Now, I also have some other MyObject objects that I would like to add to that map. However, I dont want to first read and deserialize the map back into memory, then update it and then write the whole updated map back to file. How would one update the serialization in the file in a more efficient way?

Comment: I dont think this is possible, why we use serialization then?

Comment: Seriously, do not try to edit the file directly, read the file back in and make your changes then rewrite the file.

Comment: I appreciate the quick accept, and glad that you perceived the answer and the comments as constructive. And yes, I agree: using binary serialization and the file system as persistence layer ... is not something I would recommend for anything of "real" size or importance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How would one update the serialization in the file in a more efficient way?

Basically by reverse engineering the binary protocol that Java uses when serializing objects into their binary representation. That would enable you to understand which elements in that binary blob would need to be updated in which way.

Other people have already done that, see [here](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2072752/the-java-serialization-algorithm-revealed.html) for example.

Anything else is just work. You sitting down and writing code.

Or you write the few lines of code that read in the existing files, and write out a new file with that map *plus* the other object you need in there.

You see, efficiency depends on the point of view:

- do you think the **single** update of a file with binary serialized objects is so time critical that it needs to be done by manually "patching" that binary file
- do you think it is more efficient to spend hours and hours to learn the underlying binary format, to correctly update its content?

The **only** valid reason (I can think of) why to do that: to learn exactly such things: binary data formats, and how to patch content. But even then there might be "better" assignments that give you more insights (of real value in the real world) than ... spending your time re-implementing Java binary serialization.

Comment: Yes, so that last suggestion is what I described in my question. However, imagine that the HashMap is so huge that deserializing-updating-writebackthewholemap is not feasible. You want to periodically update the serialization and only do a big costly read operation when booting the application. Is there something we can do to improve upon this naive approach?

Comment: @Saffie I agree with GhostCat, if you want to avoid performance issues, then dont use huge data in Maps, and store this info in a database or files..

Comment: If your map is so huge then storing it as a serialized file is probably the wrong use case. Store the data in a database.

Comment: Probably you guys are right about that. I'll go back to the drawing board. Thank you all!